# g++ linking OpenCV demo does not find cv::_InputArray::_InputArray and cv::imshow

Tags: opencv, g++

On one PC, I try to compile the following demo program `opencv2.cpp`, which takes images from the default video capture device in order to display them:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv; 

int main ( const int argc, const char * const * const argv ) { 
    VideoCapture cap( 0 );
    if( ! cap.isOpened() ) return 1;
    Mat frame;
    for ( ; ; ) { 
        cap >> frame;
        if ( frame.empty() ) break;
        imshow( "frame", frame );
        if ( waitKey( 10 ) == 27 ) break; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation is started with the command:

```
g++ "opencv2.cpp" -o "opencv2" -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio
```

Linking fails with the linker error:

```
/tmp/ccaEqcJr.o: In function `main':
opencv2.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
opencv2.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The Linux system runs with GCC 8.2.1 and OpenCV 3.4.1.

What puzzles me is that **I have a second PC with the very same installations of GCC and OpenCV, where compilation and linking succeeds.** Does anybody have a clue where could be the difference so that linking works only on the latter?

Comment: Note: If I comment out the line `imshow( "frame", frame );`, linking succeeds, so I guess the issue originates at the implicit conversion from `Mat&` to `InputArray&`.

Comment: Note: The issue persists without environment settings, i.e. when I compile using `env -i PATH=/usr/bin:/bin g++ "opencv2.cpp" -o "opencv2" -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio`

Comment: If I replace the line `imshow( "frame", frame );` by `const _InputArray ia( frame );`, I still get the first of the two problems flagged by the linker: `undefined reference to 'cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'`

Comment: Although the linker fails on the system, if I compile and link elsewhere, the program can run on it.

Comment: Note: A similar C language demo using OpenCV version 1 compiles and links without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The reason was that my first machine contained an outdated version of OpenCV in its /usr/local tree. After removing that, compilation and linking works just fine.